# Select field design issue after implementation of jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to Phonegap and web developement. In my project I used HTML select tag and its working fine. But when I am using jquery mobile the select tag showing two boxes, One of them looks like normal textbox and another is like dropdown.

[image: Screenshot of form]

This is the html code :-

```
<select data-placeholder="" class="form-control"
                                        id="RetailStoreName" data-rel="chosen" name="retail_id">
                                    <option>A</option>
                                    <option>B</option>
                                    <option>C</option>
                                    <option>D</option>
                                </select>
```

Please help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was my mistake. I used the jquery mobile without the css file, so I got these wrong designs. Now its working fine. Thanks :)